# react.js not load css file at all

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I build the app and I get the problem with load the CSS in part of template.

This is my CSS file `styles.module.css`:

```css
.my-page__title {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.my-page__description {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.my-page__wrapper {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

And here is the code:

```
<Box className={styles['my-page__wrapper']}>
  <Box className={styles['my-page__title']}>
    Hello!
  </Box>
  <Typography className={styles['my-page__description']}>
    Login to your acc.
  </Typography>
</Box>
```

My problem is the class `"my-page__wrapper"` and `"my-page__title"` was loaded successfully, but on the class `"my-page__description"` it does not recognize it, and it does not format the text properly.
I searched around but didn't come across a similar problem.
Does anyone know where my mistake is?

Comment: What is `<Typography>`? Is it a local component and if so can you show it, or is it a third party component?

Comment: <Typography> is mui component and mean <p>

Answer (score 1):

Mui's `Typography` component does not recognize the `className` prop. Instead you should pass your classes as an object like this:

```
<Typography classes={{
    root: styles['my-page__description']
}}>
    Login to your acc.
</Typography>
```

You can read more about overriding and extending mui class names on the [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/typography/#props)

Comment: On another page it recognized `className` and it works :/

Comment: is it possible that "page" used an older version of rect mui?

Comment: I use 4.x version of mui